# Trouble installing MySQL through Cygwin on Windows 10 "error while loading shared libraries"

Tags: mysql, windows, installation, cygwin

I'm running babun(cygwin based) shell on Windows 10, and trying to install MySQL.
I've ran:

```
$pact install mysql mysqld
```

Which executed successfully. Now, when running:

```
$mysql_install_db
```

I'm getting this error:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygwrap-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't seem to have a "cygwrap-0.dll" file on my PC. How should I properly install this?

If it helps/is related, when running:

```
$mysql -v
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql.sock'
```

Let me know what other useful information I can provide.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cygcheck -p cygwrap-0.dll
...
libwrap0-7.6-22 - libwrap0: Tools providing host-based access restrictions on 
...
```

So you need to install libwrap0